# Add periods in a string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm unable to determine why I don't get my expected output, given this code:

```
int periods = (location.Length / 2) - 1;

for (int index = 2, i = 0; i < periods; index += 3, ++i )
{
   location = location.Insert(index, ".");
}
```

And a `location` of `"C5032AC"`, I expect that `location` will equal `"C.50.32.A.C"` after my loop terminates; it is instead `"C5.03.2AC"`. Can anyone explain what I'm missing here?

Comment: What are the criteria for adding periods?

Comment: How we can figure out what *you* need????

Comment: Could you plz specify the citeria of insert :)

Comment: i will be danged.  i didn't know you could have two loop variables and increment them both

Comment: It *appears* you want a period after every character, and after every integer.  Is that correct?

Comment: @ErikPhilips that would not be accurate. Because in that case it could be C.5.0.32.A.C.

Comment: @areks In my question 50 is the integer. 5 and 0 are digits(`char.IsDigit`).

Comment: @oscilatingcretin it's a great feature, you can do something interesting stuff with for loops, including multiple variable for indexing, and multiple check variables.

Comment: My string that's coming in via a reader is "C5032AC". I need to break it down to "@.@@.@@.@.@" or "C.50.32.A.C" and store that into a string so I can print it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would investigate using regular expressions to help you achieve this goal.  You should be able to create a regular expression that matches specific patterns in the string, and you should be able to insert characters between those matches.  Please see this article [Regular Expressions MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

I've been asked to provide a bit of code to help support this.  I don't believe regular expressions are overkill, and I believe something along the lines of this example will provide at least a step in the right direction.

```
line=Regex.Replace(line,@"([\w])(\d{2})(\d{2})(\w)(\w)","$1.$2.$3.$4.$5");
```

Comment: A regex seems like overkill, but regardless this doesn't answer the question. Please at least include the regex/code you think would work.

Comment: It should be "$1.$2.$3.$4.$5" (you have a % instead of $)